# Align units of equations and units of corresponding legends below each other

Tags: horizontal-alignment, equations, tabularx, legend, units

I am using this code to align equation units of right the equation and to create nice equation legends.

**Minimum Working Example:**

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage{siunitx}

%--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
% ---- The following part is to align the units of right the equations: ---------------------
%--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

\makeatletter%
\providecommand\add@text{}%
\newcommand\addunit[1]{%
    \gdef\add@text{[\si{#1}]\gdef\add@text{}}}% 
\renewcommand\tagform@[1]{%
    \maketag@@@{\llap{\add@text\qquad}(\ignorespaces#1\unskip\@@italiccorr)}%
}%
\makeatother%

%--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
% ---- The following part is for equation legends including symbol, description and unit ----
%--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

\newenvironment{legend*}{%
    \par\vspace{\abovedisplayskip}\noindent%
    \begingroup%
    \leftskip = 3em%                                                    Indent from left, alternative 4em
    \noindent\text{\hspace{0.2em} where}%
    \par\vspace{\abovedisplayskip}\noindent%
    \tabularx{\columnwidth}{>{\(}l<{\)} @{\hspace{2em}} l @{\hspace{2em}} >{\raggedright\arraybackslash}>{[} c<{]}}}%
{\endtabularx\par\vspace{2em}%
    \par%
    \endgroup%
}%

%--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
% ---- Document part ------------------------------------------------------------------------
%--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

\begin{document}

    \begin{equation}
        V = BC       \addunit{\square\meter}
    \end{equation}

    \begin{legend*}
        V & Filter volume & \si{\cubic\meter}\\
        B & Density of the filter & \si{\kilo\gram\per\cubic\meter}\\
        C & Filter mass & \si{\kilo\gram}\\
    \end{legend*}

\end{document}
```

---

**Screenshot of the result:**

[image: Screenshot of the current state]

---

**Description of the issue:**

As you can see, this is looking nice but not perfect. Therefore I want to align the units of the legend flushed right in one line with the unit of the equation.

---

**Screenshot of the desired state:**

[image: Screenshot of the desired state]

How can I modify this code?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use an `X` column:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage{siunitx}

%--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
% ---- The following part is to align the units of right the equations: ---------------------
%--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

\makeatletter
\providecommand\add@text{}
\newcommand\addunit[1]{%
  \gdef\add@text{(\si{#1})\gdef\add@text{}}
}
\renewcommand\tagform@[1]{%
    \maketag@@@{\llap{\add@text\qquad}(\ignorespaces#1\unskip\@@italiccorr)}%
}
\makeatother

%--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
% ---- The following part is for equation legends including symbol, description and unit ----
%--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

\newenvironment{legend*}{%
    \par\vspace{\abovedisplayskip}\noindent
    \begingroup
    \tabularx{\columnwidth}{
      @{\hspace{3em}}
      >{\(}l<{\)}
      @{\hspace{2em}}
      l
      @{\hspace{2em}}
      >{\raggedright\arraybackslash}>{\hfill(} X<{)\qquad\hphantom{\theequation}}
      @{}
    }\multicolumn{3}{@{\hspace{3em}}l@{}}{where}\\[1ex]
    }%
    {\endtabularx\par\vspace{2em}%
    \par
    \endgroup
}%

%--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
% ---- Document part ------------------------------------------------------------------------
%--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

\begin{document}

    \begin{equation}
        V = BC       \addunit{\square\meter}
    \end{equation}

    \begin{legend*}
        V & Filter volume & \si{\cubic\meter}\\
        B & Density of the filter & \si{\kilo\gram\per\cubic\meter}\\
        C & Filter mass & \si{\kilo\gram}\\
    \end{legend*}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: @Dave Fixed. I would not use this alignment, though; in the equation the unit should be next to the formula, say two quads from it; in the legend, just after the description.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your help! You said *"in the equation the unit should be next to the formula, [...]; in the legend, just after the description."* Oh, is this a rule or just an opinion? :-)

Comment: @Dave Personal opinion. Do as it is common in your field.

Comment: Yes, when thinking about it - I think you are right! It is better to keep them close to each other. But something else makes me headache: Do you have an idea on how to auto-write the third table column always as `\si{<column content>}`? How can we add that to the modification? It would be nice, so in the text there is no need to write `\si{<unit>}` anymore, just <unit>...

Comment: @Dave There's the `s` column type

Comment: I am sorry, how to interpret this: When specifying the previous `X` column as a `s` column I still can not write `\si{s}` into the modification code. I think I misunderstood your intention? :-) I just want to reduce the amount of code in the main text body, therefore I want to outsource this `si{}` from the final legend content into it's configuration code.

Comment: @Dave Of course you cannot really mix X and s. It might be that the `collcell` package solves your issue.